# kde 5 plasma printer configuration module not found

Tags: printing, kde, plasma

does anybody know how I can install a printer in kde 5 plasma ? 
I cannot find a module for that in system settings :-(

os configuration is:
ubuntu 14.10, kde plasma 5, x64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no printer module yet in Plasma 5.

You can use the built-in web cups configuration. Just point a browser to `http://localhost:631`

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Install cups with `sudo apt install cups` (I'm using Arch, not Ubuntu, so I'm guessing here, but it should be that or something very similar).
2. Then start + enable the cups service, i.e. `sudo systemctl start cups` and `sudo systemctl enable cups`. After that, you should already be able to manage your printers on your browser at http://localhost:631.
3. [Optional] If you want to use the KDE System Settings to manage your printers then you need to install the KDE print manager (the package's name is "print-manager" so you'll probably get it installed with `sudo apt install print-manager`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good printer configuration module at the KDE Software center.  The software center is bundled with KDE Plasma.  Wait for the list to update, and type 'printers' in the search box.

Comment: I'd consider improving the description of your answer, and possibly add an image or two for easier navigation. Thanks for contributing!